# Rails 4 error: undefined 'model_name' for FamilyMember::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

client_controller.rb

```
  def spouse
    @title   = 'Spouse Information'
    @partial = 'spouse_form'
    @client_query  = Client.find(params[:id])
    binding.pry
    if @client_query.family_members.empty?
      @client = :family_members
    else
      @client = Client.find(params[:id]).family_members
    end
    render 'new'
  end

  def create_spouse
    @family_member = FamilyMember.new(family_members_params)
    binding.pry
    if @family_member.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'profile'
    end
  end
```

client.rb

```
  has_many :family_members, dependent: :destroy
```

family_member.rb

```
  belongs_to :client, foreign_key: 'client_id'
```

and my form

```
.box-content
  = form_for(@client, url: create_spouse_client_path, method: 'post', html: { class: 'form-horizontal', style: 'margin-bottom: 0;' }) do |f|
    = f.hidden_field :is_form_complete, value: false
    = f.hidden_field :client_id, :value => @client_query.id
    = render partial: 'spouse_fields', locals: { f: f }
    .form-actions.form-actions-padding-sm
      .row
        .col-md-10.col-md-offset-2
          = f.submit "Next", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary"
```

I got error on:

```
  = form_for(@client, url: create_spouse_client_path, method: 'post', html: { class: 'form-horizontal', style: 'margin-bottom: 0;' }) do |f|
```

and it says:

```
undefined method `model_name' for FamilyMember::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:Class
```

I can't view the form because fields is not empty. What's wrong about my code? Plese help.

Comment: Your `view code` is related to which `action` of your `controller`?

Comment: What does this line `@client = :family_members` do?

Comment: @client = :family_members, i use that line of code for preventing error if family_member of the client has empty. so the form_for will become form_for :family_members do ... blah blah